# How to redirect using .htaccess and database?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basically I am creating a URL shortener. I have stored URLs in my Database and each URL has unique ID. So what I want now is that whenever somebody visits `http://localhost/anyfolder/4`
(Here `4` is the ID of the URL, say http://google.com) then he should be redirected to http://google.com. I hope you got my point. Currently with my knowledge I have created following .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(redirect\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?l=$1 [L]
```

I also have one redirect.php file but don't know how to code it in a way so that it can redirect. Please tell me that how can I code it in such a way so that it can redirect properly. Just want to tell that might be my .htaccess file is also wrong. So if you know then please help me out!

**EDIT :** I have two more files. One is simple index.html

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
URL(with "http://"): <input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the other is process.php which does all the work of storing and giving back the user his unique ID

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","url");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
$url = $_POST['url'];
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO url (url)VALUES('$url')");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM url WHERE url='$url'");
while($id = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo " URL Shortened Successfully! ".'<br>'."Your shortened URL is ";
  echo 'http://localhost/redirect/' . $id['id'];
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please share your PHP code too.

Comment: @BenM I have added my PHP code also, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Please, please, please learn about SQL injection...

Comment: I know that it's not secure, because it's just for test purposes. Please tell me how can I use my DB and .htaccess to redirect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

redirect.php

```
<?php
$LocationId = (isset($_GET['l'])) ? $_GET['l'] : null;

if( $LocationId )
{
    $DBConn = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Connection Error");

    $Resut  = mysqli_query($DBConn, 
                sprintf("SELECT url FROM url WHERE id LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,1", 
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConn, $LocationId)
                )
          ) or die( mysqli_error($DBConn) );

    if( $Resut )
    {
        $Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Resut);

        if( isset($Row['url']) && !empty($Row['url']) )
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header(sprintf('Location: %s', $Row['url']));
            exit;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: it is giving me an error which says `Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirect\redirect.php on line 8` any solution?

Comment: You've switched the order of the arguments for `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: ok now it gives me some other error :

`Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirect\redirect.php on line 8`

`Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirect\redirect.php on line 8`

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirect\redirect.php on line 8`

Comment: @nigro.simone There is a problem with .htaccess It is actually parsing every page of this folder htpp://localhost/redirect to http://localhost/redirect/redirect.php ...I just want to parse the pages that are visited as http://localhost/redirect/redirect.php/1 or any other number. Please help me out in this!